# Syntax error with if in function definition

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have this code:

```
def rho(switch,y,h):
    if switch=1:
        return 1.255
    if switch=2:
        return 1.255*np.exp(-y/h)
```

apparently the `if` statement has a syntax error, I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

```
def rho(switch,y,h):
    if switch == 1:
        return 1.255
    if switch == 2:
        return 1.255*np.exp(-y/h)
```

`==` instead of `=` inside `if` statements